# how to save values to magento customer module default stored attributes in magento2?

Tags: magento2, attributes, customer-attribute, zipcode

> I have created new filed in Magento 2 registration form

**I want to save the values to default stored attributes**

(if Zip code =>  default in Magento 2 attributes)

**How to pass the values to that attribute ??**

Comment: do you want to save data in `zip code` field ?

Comment: ssss/...........................